# Why do edit links in this Rails view have the same id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, erb

In this model, scheduled games and players are nested resources of franchise, with routing set up as follows:

```
OTH::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :franchises do
    resources :scheduled_games
    resources :players
  end
```

I can create these model objects correctly. But I must be doing something wrong in the view, which looks like this:

```
<% @franchise.scheduled_games.each do |game| %>
  <p class="games">
    <span class="date">   
    <b>Opponent:</b>  <%= game.opponent %> 
    <b>date:</b>    <%= game.date %>

  <%= link_to 'Edit',edit_franchise_scheduled_game_path(@franchise) %> 
  </span> </p>
<% end %>
```

There are two things that are going wrong when this view is displayed. The worst is that each edit link has the same id for the nested resource (/franchises/1/scheduled_games/1/edit) even  though the other information for the item is correct.

Second is that a blank record always displays.

Where have I gone wrong?

**Update** Here is the output of rake routes:

```
franchise_scheduled_games 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
POST   /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
 new_franchise_scheduled_game 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
edit_franchise_scheduled_game 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
     franchise_scheduled_game 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
PUT    /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}
DELETE /franchises/:franchise_id/scheduled_games/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"scheduled_games"}

franchise_players 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/players(.:format)                  {:action=>"index", :controller=>"players"}
POST   /franchises/:franchise_id/players(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"players"}
         new_franchise_player 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/players/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"players"}
        edit_franchise_player 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/players/:id/edit(.:format)         {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"players"}
             franchise_player 
GET    /franchises/:franchise_id/players/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"show", :controller=>"players"}
PUT    /franchises/:franchise_id/players/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"update", :controller=>"players"}
DELETE /franchises/:franchise_id/players/:id(.:format)              {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"players"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `game` as well when [using `link_to` with nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects):

```
edit_franchise_scheduled_game_path(@franchise, game)
```

Comment: I tried that (it was the first thing I tried), but get a routing error.

Comment: What's the routing error? It might be helpful to look at the output of `rake routes` as well.

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"scheduled_games", :franchise_id=>  If I input the /franchises/1/scheduled_games/2/edit url directly, I get the proper view.

Comment: I think I see part of the problem, in the parameters part of the routing error, I see #<ScheduledGame id: nil, ....>,

Comment: @KevDog Are the scheduled games loaded from `@franchise.schedule_games` saved? I.e., do they have IDs?

Comment: Looked at the db, all of the scheduled games have an id.

Answer (score 0):

Because they use the REST pattern, so if you want to delete a resource you use the HTTP/Delete request to the same url as you would for a GET request.